# Invoke Action Method from Clicking a button in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, button, controller

I want to know if I can call a method in the controller when a button is clicked.

I have a view called `home` and when the view is loaded, it invokes the `Index` action method in the controller. I have a `Button` (HTML or ASP.NET) called `LoadData`. When I click the button, I need to load some data in the same view called `Home`.

How do I do that?

Comment: @engineerachu I edited out the incorrect terminology. With ASP.NET MVC, do not use ASP.NET controls *button or otherwise*. This is not ASP.NET -- the Home.aspx isn't a page -- it's a view. It doesn't actually correspond to a physical page. That's an important distinction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With buttons, it has to involve JQuery or JavaScript to make a call to get the data from the server, if you want to do it in AJAX form.  But in its simplest form, doing:

```
<% Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller"); %>

 <!--Form values in here-->

 <input type="submit" />

<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

Will invoke your action method and invoke a postback.  There is an AJAX option in the System.Web.Mvc.Ajax to use an AjaxForm with AJAX options for doing the postback async, and it's easy to setup.  I tend to use JQuery instead personally.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

To do this using a simple post, you just need to post to the URL at which the controller method exists.

For example, following the standard routes setup in your global.asax "{controller}/{action}/{id}"

If you have a controller method inside your HomeController class called "LoadData" then you'd access it at the URL:

/Home/LoadData

This is the URL you'd enter into your forms `action` attribute.

You can also hit this URL using an AJAX request in order to load data into the same page you're on without any postback.

Using jQuery you could do something like:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
                   $.post(
                            this.action,{params},
                            function(data){ // do something with return info }
                  }
```

Comment: Yeah, I knew I can do it using jQuery, but first I'm trying to work with asp.net only then move to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You Define two action one for show the empty view and one for populating the view with a list :

```
public ViewResult Empty()
    {
        var products = productsRepository.Products.Where(x => x.ProductID == -1);
        return View();
    }
```

and :

```
public ViewResult ListAll()
    {
        var products = productsRepository.Products;
        return View("Empty", products);
    }
```

and in your view Empty.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<DomainModel.Entities.Product>>" %>
```

Empty

```
<h2>Empty</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            ProductID
        </th>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>
        <th>
            Price
        </th>
        <th>
            Category
        </th>
        <th>
            ImageMimeType
        </th>
        <th>
            Error
        </th>
    </tr>

<% if (Model != null) 
   {
       foreach (var item in Model)
       { %>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ProductID })%> |
            <%= Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ProductID })%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.ProductID)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.Name)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.Description)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:F}", item.Price))%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.Category)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.ImageMimeType)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.Error)%>
        </td>
    </tr>

<% }
   }%>

</table>

<p>
    <%= Html.ActionLink("List Products", "ListAll")%>

</p>
```

hope this helps

Comment: How this works? Like when "ListAll" link is clicked, the "ListAll" method fires or what? And what is "ViewResult" class mean?

Comment: yes when the ListAll link is clicked the ListAll method is invoked.
there is some kin of result that action method may return one of them is View so ViewResult returns back a view here Empty.aspx view with the products list as ViewModel. as its shows you are very new to MVC so I recommed you to take a look to http://www.asp.net/MVC you find great viedos and tutorials ther and you may ask your question at ASP.NET MVC Forum (http://forums.asp.net/1146.aspx) to get the proper answers if mine is not good enough.
hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You've to write your Controller as follows.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult FetchData()
    {
        return Content("Some data...");
    }

}
```

And call the desired action as follows.

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("FetchData", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "ContentPlaceHolder", HttpMethod = "Post" }))
   { %>
<div id="ContentPlaceHolder"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Fetch Data" />
<% } %>

<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```