# Set and change the OptionSetValue of crm in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5, dynamics-crm-2011

I am working on mvc-5 with dynamic-crm. In crm i have a optionsetValue for state-code with the value (publish,deactivate,draft). Now my first question is how do i set these value in my C# code,by default it should be draft. The second is how do i change the state-code value on button click(say when i click on publish button the state should change to publish from draft). 
below is the code that i have in my model

```
[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.AttributeLogicalNameAttribute("statuscode")]
public Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue statuscode
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetAttributeValue<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue>("statuscode");
    }
    set
    {

        this.SetAttributeValue("statuscode", value);

    }
}

[DisplayName("Status")]
[Display(Name = "Status")]
public string Status
{
    get
    {
        if(statuscode == null)
        {
            OptionSetValue setValue = new OptionSetValue();
            setValue.Value = 1;
            return Status = "Draft";          
        }

        return Status = statuscode.Value.ToString() == "1" ? "Publish" : "Draft";
    }
    set
    {

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

In `Dynamics CRM` when we create a new record, the if we specify or not. The default value for the `StateCode` and `StatusCode` is set.

So we have to set `Status(statecode)` and `Status Reason(statuscode)` explicitly.
Below is the function i am using in my code:

```
public static void SetStatus(string EntityName, Guid Id, int StateCode, int StatusCode)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Service == null)
                throw GRID.CRM.ExceptionHandler.ExceptionUtil.GetException("Connection with CRM is Lost", typeof(Common), "SetStatus");
            SetStateRequest StateRequest = new SetStateRequest();
            StateRequest.EntityMoniker = new EntityReference(EntityName, Id);
            StateRequest.State = new OptionSetValue(StateCode);
            StateRequest.Status = new OptionSetValue(StatusCode);
            SetStateResponse StateResponse = (SetStateResponse)Service.Execute(StateRequest);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw GRID.CRM.ExceptionHandler.ExceptionUtil.GetException(ex, typeof(Common), "SetStatus");
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but where exactly should i write this code in mvc and how do i change the value on button control

Comment: @user3438650 i think, that is related to MVC, you need to  learn how to call a function on button click:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503923/html-button-calling-a-mvc-controller-and-action-method


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945468/invoke-action-method-from-clicking-a-button-in-asp-net-mvc